# How to find apache-jakarta?

Tags: java, sms, smslib

I want to include SMSLib in java and there are certain requirements to accomplish that. i followed the instructions but i found that i must include apache-jakarta as one of the steps,
but i can't find apache-jakarta anywhere to download, and in the main website i got a something like jakarta retired. any one know how to get rid of that issue as without it even the main SMSLib packages didn't recognized:

```
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.http.BulkSmsHTTPGateway;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From webpage of smslib.org.

> Prerequisites
>
> To use SMSLib, you should install the following components:
>
> - SUN JDK 1.6 or newer.
> - Java Communications Library.
> - Apache ANT for building the sources.
> - Apache log4j.
> - Apache Jakarta Commons - NET.
> - JSMPP Library

Apache Jakarta Commons - NET is found at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

Comment: well, thanks, but now i had follow all the instructions and still can't recognize the library in eclipse, do you have an idea about what can cause that ? and does it differ when using win-64 ??

Answer (score 1):

Most of the "Jakarta" stuff has moved into Apache Commons (http://commons.apache.org/)

What are the specific libraries required?

Comment: well, thanks for your help , but now i had follow all the instructions and still can't recognize the library in eclipse, do you have an idea about what can cause that ? and does it differ when using win-64 ??

Comment: If there are native components to the libraries, you may need to use a different version of the library for 32 vs 64 bit. The documentation should mention that.

Comment: the documentation mentioned that if i'm using win-32 i must do bla bla bla , but if i have Solaris or Linux i must do bla bla bla, and nothing mentioned about if i'm using win-64, and in the given download links there is no talk about the windows type, only they offer me to download tar or zip.